# How to upload file to Group Drive (Shared Drive) with Google Drive API V3?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a question how do I upload a file to Group Drive (Shared Drive) with Google Drive API?

I have tried parent id for that folder (Group Drive) but that does not seem to work.

```
public uploadFile(stream, totalSize, mime, fileName, parentId?, callback?) {
    //Init upload
    this.emit('progress', {
        type: 'file',
        name: fileName,
        uploaded: 0,
        size: totalSize
    });
    debug('Uploading file %s with parentId: %s', fileName, parentId);
    //start upload
    var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: this.oauth2Client });
    var fileMetadata = {
        name: fileName,
        mimeType: mime,
        'parents': [
            "0AFiiwdVdxetuUk9PVA"
        ],
        'teamDriveId': "0AFiiwdVdxetuUk9PVA"
    }
    if (parentId) {
        fileMetadata['parents'] = [parentId];
    }
    var req = drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: {
            mimeType: mime,
            body: stream
        }
    }, (err, resp) => {
        debug('Uploaded %s to Drive Successfully', fileName);
        this.emit("fileUploaded", {
            size: totalSize,
            name: fileName,
            error: err
        });
        if (callback)
            callback(err, resp);
    });
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.emit("progress", {
            type: 'file',
            name: fileName,
            uploaded: req.req.connection.bytesWritten,
            size: totalSize
        });
        if (req.req.connection.bytesWritten >= totalSize) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, SPEED_TICK_TIME);
    return req;
}
```

This is what I have tried and I get this error:

```
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)   code: 404,   errors:    [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'notFound',
       message: 'File not found: 0AFiiwdVdxetuUk9PVA.',
       locationType: 'parameter',
       location: 'fileId' } ] }
```

Comment: Just update the question with the code which  you have tried,

Comment: Best thing to start with when you are starting to work on a product is to check on the existing documentation, try to revisit ["Upload files"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) in the Drive API documentation.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 there is nothing about group drive (shared drive) uploading.

Comment: @pa1.Shetty I have added some code.

Comment: It says `File not found: 0AFiiwdVdxetuUk9PVA` are you sure about the folder with the id  0AFiiwdVdxetuUk9PVA ?If so make the folder as sharable and try.

Comment: @pa1.Sheety I'm sure, it works when I try in google test api (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) but it my code it does not.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have figured it out. Turns out I just needed to add supportsAllDrives and driveId insted of teamDriveId.

```
public uploadFile(stream, totalSize, mime, fileName, parentId?, callback?) {
    //Init upload
    this.emit('progress', {
        type: 'file',
        name: fileName,
        uploaded: 0,
        size: totalSize
    });
    debug('Uploading file %s with parentId: %s', fileName, parentId);
    //start upload
    var drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: this.oauth2Client });
    var fileMetadata = {
        name: fileName,
        driveId: "0AFiiwdVdxetuUk9PVA",
        mimeType: mime
    }
    if (parentId) {
        fileMetadata['parents'] = [parentId];
    } else {
        fileMetadata['parents'] = ["0AFiiwdVdxetuUk9PVA"];
    }
    var req = drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: {
            mimeType: mime,
            body: stream
        },
        supportsAllDrives: true,
    }, (err, resp) => {
        debug('Uploaded %s to Drive Successfully', fileName);
        this.emit("fileUploaded", {
            size: totalSize,
            name: fileName,
            error: err
        });
        if (callback)
            callback(err, resp);
    });
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.emit("progress", {
            type: 'file',
            name: fileName,
            uploaded: req.req.connection.bytesWritten,
            size: totalSize
        });
        if (req.req.connection.bytesWritten >= totalSize) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, SPEED_TICK_TIME);
    return req;
}
```