# Google Drive API returns Folder ID 404 but the folder ID is correct

Tags: javascript, api, python-requests, google-drive-api

so I'm trying to upload some files to a particular Folder, I have its and it works perfectly when querying. However, when I try to upload to that folder I get a 404 error.

```
var file = document.getElementById('input-file').files[0];
var metadata = {
      'mimeType': file.type,
    'name': name, // Filename at Google Drive
    'parents': ['0AN75N3P23eTJUk9PVA'], // Folder ID at Google Drive
};

var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; // Here gapi is used for retrieving the access token.
var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' }));
form.append('file', file);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(xhr.response.id); // Retrieve uploaded file ID.
};
xhr.send(form);
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps the problem is with `'name': name` ... is it defined somewhere NOT on the global scope?

Comment: @JaromandaX nope! I checked the value, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add 'supportsAllDrives: true' in the form because the folder is a shared drive as per [How to upload file to Group Drive (Shared Drive) with Google Drive API V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452507/how-to-upload-file-to-group-drive-shared-drive-with-google-drive-api-v3)