# IOS : How to upload file to Group Drive (Shared Drive)?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I'm trying to export my file to Google **Share Drive**. I was able to export to my own drive but I have not found any solution for the shared one yet.

Currently, what I have so far for uploading file to my drive are these two functions, one will be a public function that will simplify the interface, and another one will actually upload the file:

```
    public func uploadFile(
        _ folderName: String,
        filePath: String,
        MIMEType: String,
        onCompleted: ((String?, Error?) -> ())?) {
            
        search(folderName) { (folderID, error) in
                
            if let ID = folderID {
                self.upload(ID, path: filePath, MIMEType: MIMEType, onCompleted: onCompleted)
                
                // if not found, create a new one
            } else {
                self.createFolder(folderName, onCompleted: { (folderID, error) in
                    guard let ID = folderID else {
                        onCompleted?(nil, error)
                        return
                    }
                    self.upload(ID, path: filePath, MIMEType: MIMEType, onCompleted: onCompleted)
                })
            }
        }
    }
        // upload
    private func upload(
        _ parentID: String,
        path: String,
        MIMEType: String,
        onCompleted: ((String?, Error?) -> ())?) {
            
        ...
    }
```

Now I want to upload my files to a shared Drive and I found there are DriveID and Parent properties from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452507/how-to-upload-file-to-group-drive-shared-drive-with-google-drive-api-v3) but it is Node.js and not so sure how to work with it with iOS.

```
var fileMetadata = {
    name: fileName,
    mimeType: mime,
    'parents': [
        "0AFiiwdVdxetuUk9PVA"
    ],
    'teamDriveId': "0AFiiwdVdxetuUk9PVA"
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what errors are you encountering.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, I have updated my question, there is no error, I just dont know how to save my files to a Shared Google Drive

Answer (score 1):

You must add the `supportsAllDrives=true` query parameter to your upload request url.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives

Comment: thank you so much for this suggestion, I will try it soon <3